# Limiting the MTU for one application without Administrator permissions on Windows

Tags: windows, networking, java, mtu

I do have an Java Console application that is sending packets via the internet connection.
The application is running on a Windows 10 machine, with Oracle JDK 11/17.

I need to adapt the MTU size that the application is using to send the packets.
But I do not have administrative rights on that Windows machine.
Is there a way with a JVM argument or other Windows Parameters?

Up to now I would only know it for the NIC with administrative rights.

Comment: I am agreeing with you, not myself.

Comment: @Ramhound: but why the source code? usually that is only on the NIC. the applications should not care about that low level transport aspect.